# Calculating limit-help needed (difference of cubes)

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm stuck trying to find this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x-1)}-x)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this precalculus, or can you use Taylor series?

Comment: I'm not sure about Taylor series, I'm not there yet. This is more like when you learn limits for the first time. I tried doing this by completing the difference of cubes, but didn't get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem had a square root instead of a cube root, you probably know how to proceed. For example,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \big( \sqrt{(x-2)(x-1)} - x \big) &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{(x-2)(x-1)} - x)(\sqrt{(x-2)(x-1)} + x)}{\sqrt{(x-2)(x-1)} + x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x-2)(x-1) - x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} + x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-3x+2}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2} + x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-3+2/x}{\sqrt{1-3/x+2/x^2} + 1} = -\frac{3}{2}.
\end{align*}
That approach uses the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ (with $a=\sqrt{(x-2)(x-1)}$ and $b=x$).

Given the identity $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, can you use a similar method in your problem?

Comment: I just saw you comment: "I tried doing this by completing the difference of cubes, but didn't get the right answer." This is why you put that information *in the original question*. I could have spent my time giving you the help you actually want, instead of motivating something you already knew.

Comment: Sorry about that, Greg! This is my first question here...I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Wouldn't you complete the identity in the numerator rather than in denominator?

Comment: Thanks, Stefan ... I should have seen that you were new to the site and made allowances. And yes, I totally had my fractions upside down - good catch! - I've fixed them.

Comment: Here is how I'd go about it:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}-x)(\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}^2+x\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}+x^3)}{\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}^2+x\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}+x^3}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(x-2)^2(x+1)-x^3}{\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}^2+x\sqrt[3]{(x-2)^2(x+1)}+x^3}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-3x^2+4}{\sqrt[3]{(x^3-3x^2+4)}^2+x\sqrt[3]{(x^3-3x^2+4)}+x^3}=0$$

but it should be -1. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: In the first line, the last $x^3$ on top and bottom should be $x^2$.